# Fading carousel in boostrap 4 in style of jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've found a design I quite like with the jumbotron, but I'd like to fade images in the background, which I've read is best used when running on the carousel.

I came across a [great example of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967616/cycle-through-background-image-of-bootstrap-3-jumbotron) that even centers images, but after matching the base layout, I'm having trouble fully combining the styles, and it doesn't work in bootstrap 4 which I'd prefer to be using.

Here is the relevant HTML and CSS code (with links showing it working):

Working boostrap 3: https://www.bootply.com/iW6Tn3ks6I

Preferred style (including the nav bar): https://www.bootply.com/LdBa0MzdpV

I've already made a bunch of tweaks, but my CSS knowledge is limited and I'm not sure where to go from here. For example, the jumbotron text has a ton of padding and I can't seem to find which line of the CSS relates to it.

Edit: Got the transitions working, but the fade doesn't do anything and I can't vertically center the text when resizing the window (either `top` or `bottom` can be set in `carousel-overlay`, but not both) - https://www.bootply.com/Vq9kNFcfPA

Edit 2: Modified the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431138/fade-transition-for-carousel-in-bootstrap-4-beta) and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add what is need to your css.

```
<div class="header clearfix">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3"><h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 float-right"><nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

body {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

/* Custom page header */
.header {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: .05rem solid #e5e5e5;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */
.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 3rem;
}


/* Carousel Fade Effect */
.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    opacity: .5;
}
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.right {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}

.carousel-overlay h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
}


.slide1, .slide2, .slide3 {
  min-height: 560px; /* Must have a height or min-height set due to use of background images */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.slide1 {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/300);
}
.slide2 {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1100/300);
}
.slide3 {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1200/300);
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though it still doesn't solve the issue of uneven padding and not working with bootstrap 4 :P

Comment: change your html only the header div to what I edit it to.

Comment: Alright cheers, it works for getting the nav bar working in bootstrap 3, I'll fall back to this if I can't get the carousel working in 4 :)